# Java method parsing text returning StringIndexOutOfBoundsException only for positive numbers

Tags: java, string, indexing, substring, stringindexoutofbounds

I have a method that parses line of text, such as `24/11/2018, Drive, -2.00,` and returns the number before the last comma, this case being `-2`. Here is the method:

```
public static int value (String line){
    //-5 becasue of characters after dot, t1 becomes "24/11/2018, Drive, -2"
    String t1= red.substring(0, red.length()-5);  
    String t2=t1.substring(t1.lastIndexOf(','+1));
    return Integer.parseInt(t2);
}
```

This method has no problem working with negative values such as the case above, but when the value is positive like this line `15/11/2018, Tata, 50.00,` I get the StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1927)
at ParseCSV.vrijednost(ParseCSV.java:30)
at Main.main(Main.java:30)
```

Which points at the line `String t2=t1.substring(t1.lastIndexOf(','+1));`, and at the String class at `throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);`. I suppose this means that my begin index `t1.lastIndexOf(','+1)` is nowhere to be found, meaning that there is no `,` character even though it clearly is there. This problem appears only for positive values and I have no idea why.

Comment: Note that you do `',' + 1` i.e. you add one onto a comma. This results in the character after comma in the character table. So you do not search for comma, but for the other character.

Comment: Don't guess and assume, just check it. Print the result and see what it actually is. `System.out.println(t1.lastIndexOf(','+1);`. (Or learn to use a debugger)

Comment: @Aomine yes that was the problem, +1 was in the brackets, thank you!